# Typ matching query does not exist. should be easy but cant figure it out

Tags: django, django-urls

I really need your help here.

i have an app and i want it to generate a link. the whole thing works in the first step. but when you are on the second page and click on the next link i get an:

Typ matching query does not exist.

my code generates a wrong link:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/typ/Richie%20Eisler/
```

the problem is the autofill slug for this link is:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/typ/richie-eisler/
```

when i enter the upper from hand i get to the right page - it gets created and works. and I dont know where it hands over the wrong link. it looks like it passes the name Field (which is "Richie Eisler") instead of the slug.

i did exactly the same thing before and it works just fine and i cant figure out whats wrong.
it tells me the mistake is in this line:

```
typ         = Typ.objects.get(slug=typslug)
```

this is the not working view:

```
def Typen(request, typslug):
    typ         = Typ.objects.get(slug=typslug)
    context     = {'typ': typ}
    return render_to_response('typ.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and this is from the url.py

(r'^typ/(?P.*)/$', 'sk8.views.Typen'),

This is exactly the "same" but works:

```
def SpeziellerSk8(request, sk8slug):
    sk8         = Sk8.objects.get(slug=sk8slug)
    context     = {'sk8' : sk8}
    return render_to_response('diesersk8.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))


 (r'^skates/(?P<sk8slug>.*)/$', 'sk8.views.SpeziellerSk8'),
```

Comment: How do you generate the link?

Answer (score 0):

Ive just figured it out.

the problem was in the template.

this is the right way to do it:

```
<p>Typ: <a href="/typ/{{sk8.typ.slug}}/">{{sk8.typ}}</a></p>
```

and this is what i had before

```
<p>Typ: <a href="/typ/{{sk8.typ}}/">{{sk8.typ}}</a></p>
```

i figured as he was creating the link but then going to the wrong one the mistake must be within the link.
the link is created in the Template.
so i checked the template and found that i had the link messed up.

i hope this helps is somebody else has a similar problem.

cheers
daniel